# Failed on installing TPLINK Archer T1U WiFi dongle on Raspbian Jessie

Tags: wifi, pi-zero, driver

1. The driver download page is here, http://www.tp-link.com/us/download/Archer-T1U.html#Driver.
2. In the .pdf instruction it says that I need to edit configuration in `makefile.c`.
3. However, there is no `makefile.c`, instead there is `Makefile.inc` with the same content as described in .pdf instruction.
4. So, I assume the `makefile.c` mentioned in the .pdf instruction is actually `Makefile.inc`.
5. I changed nothing in the `Makefile.inc`.
6. I run `sudo make`. It returns error `*** /lib/modules/4.4.38-v7+/build: No such file or directory. Stop.`
7. Copy `Makefile.inc` into `makefile.c`, then run `sudo make` again, same result.

   - `lsusb` returns `Bus 001 Device 007: ID 2357:0105` for this dongle.
   - I use Raspbian Jessie. Currently attaching this in my Raspberry PI 3. However, I will use this dongle in Raspberry PI Zero.
   - I suspect that I choose wrong target platform. At this case I choose `PC` as the target platform in `Makefile.inc`.

Here are other target platform in the `Makefile.inc`.

- PC
- 5VT
- IKANOS_V160
- IKANOS_V180
- SIGMA
- SIGMA_8622
- INIC
- STAR
- IXP
- INF_TWINPASS
- INF_DANUBE
- INF_AR9
- INF_VR9
- BRCM_6358
- INF_AMAZON_SE
- CAVM_OCTEON
- CMPC
- RALINK_2880
- RALINK_3052
- SMDK
- RMI
- RMI_64
- KODAK_DC
- DM6446
- FREESCALE8377
- BL2384
- BL23570
- BLUBB
- BLPMP
- MT85XX
- MT53XX
- NXP_TV550
- MVL5
- RALINK_3352
- UBICOM_IPX8
- INTELP6

EDIT 1, I tried to install this in my Ubuntu MATE 16.04 laptop, with same settings as above. This returns these errors.

```
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
scripts/Makefile.build:258: recipe for target '/home/xxxxx/Downloads/Archer_T1U_V1_150909/Driver/MODULE/os/linux/../../sta/sta_cfg.o' failed
make[3]: *** [/home/xxxxx/Downloads/Archer_T1U_V1_150909/Driver/MODULE/os/linux/../../sta/sta_cfg.o] Error 1
Makefile:1420: recipe for target '_module_/home/xxxxx/Downloads/Archer_T1U_V1_150909/Driver/MODULE/os/linux' failed
make[2]: *** [_module_/home/xxxxx/Downloads/Archer_T1U_V1_150909/Driver/MODULE/os/linux] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-59-generic'
Makefile:548: recipe for target 'osdrv' failed
make[1]: *** [osdrv] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/xxxxx/Downloads/Archer_T1U_V1_150909/Driver/MODULE'
Makefile:3: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: Splurge $15 on a known working adapter. Out-of-tree drivers on linux fall into one or both of two categories 1) Proprietary closed source things; 2) Stuff that was never submitted, or *rejected*, for inclusion in the mainline kernel.   The former tend to be impossible on the Pi because they are pre-compiled for x86(-64); at a glance this isn't that.  The stuff in the second category is likely to be poorly written and maintained.  In any case, this is probably only the beginning of your headache; it is then a matter of how many hours you want to waste before you give up.

Comment: My WiPi in on the way.

Answer (score 1):

About five hours of searching and about 6GB of downloads later (one guide had me download the entire kernel source, 2.5GB as well as a bunch of different versions of it) I got!

MrEngman on the Raspberry Pi forums is godsend, he made a script which automatically selects the correct wifi driver for the kernel and installs it.

Here's what to do:

1. Download http://www.fars-robotics.net/install-wifi to your pi. It's a shell script. The rest of the instructions are copied from the top of the script:
2. `sudo mv install-wifi /usr/bin/install-wifi`
3. `sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/install-wifi`
4. `sudo install-wifi`

This works perfectly for me. It also supports monitor mode which is awesome! I've verified that it works on `4.9.41-v7+` and the bleeding edge build `4.9.54+`

Comment: Will this work with all consumer WiFi dongle or just the specific ones? I ended up buying WiPi for my Raspberry PI Zero. This was before RPI Zero W released. Thanks for posting regardless.

Comment: He has compiled a specific set of drivers. The majority of usb cards work out of the box with raspbian though.