# Install Archer T1U driver on Ubuntu Mate

Tags: ubuntu, driver, wireless-adapter

I am trying to install a driver for [this](https://www.tp-link.com/us/download/Archer-T1U.html#Driver) wireless dongle but it states that the drivers can be built only on kernel versions 2.6~3.16. While mine is:

```
uname -a
Linux pi-raspberry11 4.4.38-v7+ #938 SMP Thu Dec 15 15:22:21 GMT 2016 armv7l armv7l armv7l GNU/Linux
```

I tried following the answer from this [question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/60949/failed-on-installing-tplink-archer-t1u-wifi-dongle-on-raspbian-jessie) but after rebooting I cannot ssh to the Raspberry, and after booting instead of showing the desktop it shows a blank screen.

How can I make the Archer T1U(EU) work on a Raspberry Pi?